# Is there a standalone node-template that points to the polkadot-sdk repo?

Tags: substrate-node-template, substrate-node, versioning

Are there are node templates that one can use readily without tinkering with the versions and tags? Something that works out of the box?

And it should point to the [polkadot-sdk repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk) and not the deprecated [substrate repo](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate.git). So [this one here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/) for instance points to the deprecated repo on all branches and tags that I have checked out. And this one here on the new [polkadot-sdk repo](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/polkadot-v1.8.0/substrate/bin/node-template) points obviously to itself consistently. But it doesnt seem to have a Cargo.toml at the root of https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/polkadot-v1.8.0/substrate/bin/node-template, so for me as a novice it is not clear what gets compiles when executing

```
cargo build --release
```

at the level of the node-template directory. But it goes on for 16 minutes and does something, and it does it successfully

```
Compiling polkadot-node-core-provisioner v7.0.0 (/home/myname/path/to/repo/polkadot-sdk/polkadot/node/core/provisioner)
   Compiling polkadot-node-core-dispute-coordinator v7.0.0 (/home/myname/path/to/repo/polkadot-sdk/polkadot/node/core/dispute-coordinator)
   Compiling polkadot-approval-distribution v7.0.0 (/home/myname/path/to/repo/polkadot-sdk/polkadot/node/network/approval-distribution)
   Compiling polkadot-availability-distribution v7.0.0 (/home/myname/path/to/repo/polkadot-sdk/polkadot/node/network/availability-distribution)
   Compiling polkadot-service v7.0.0 (/home/myname/path/to/repo/polkadot-sdk/polkadot/node/service)
   Compiling polkadot-cli v7.0.0 (/home/myname/path/to/repo/polkadot-sdk/polkadot/cli)
   Compiling polkadot v6.0.0 (/home/myname/path/to/repo/polkadot-sdk/polkadot)
    Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 16m 28s
```

and there is no `./target` branch appearing anywhere in the directory structure, not even at the root of the entire mono-repo.

What other options are there to start building? I looked at the https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template but it, too, points to the deprecated repository (all the crates inside the Cargo.toml do).

then there is this one https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node which is a specialized node template as far as i can see. I cant quite understand the Cargo.tomls because they just reference the crates without specifying the repo. But at least in the README.md just the first link is to the deprecated substrate repo.

So I am wondering how a new developer should start hacking? Is there anywhere a node template out there that is not deprecated? Or if not, is there maybe a clear instruction of how to create one? Replacing the git link and tag is not straight forward. one would have to then replace all the versions to the correct versions and in the end one has created a node template by oneself and by then probably understands the ins and outs of substrate so much that one doesn't even need the template anymore. But as a novice it is quite hard to get started to be honest.

Comment: I tried contact them and see if I can help with maintaining those repos. Parity is under a big refactoring now. A lot of things doesn't work well as before and I'm pretty sad with current situation.